# Webpack history-api-fallback not load javascript from root path

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Here is my code for setting up history-api-fallback in "webpack.config.js"

```
    devServer: {
            historyApiFallback:{
                index:'/dist/index.html'
            }
        }
```

Webpack works find.

When it cannot find path, it will go to index.html then index.html call javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js"></script>
```

**The problem** is "index.html" load javascript from the path that call, not go to find .js in the root path.

Example :

1. http://localhost:8080/a/b/c/

[image]

2. http://localhost:8080/a/b/

[image]

Comment: I posted an answer to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352703/webpack-historyapifallback-configuration-for-deep-routes